# Ajuda validar resultados separadamente JavaScript

Tags: javascript, funções

Olá, tenho essa questão pra resolver, faço a fórmula para encontrar o maior valor dos dois números, mas estou com dificuldade pra validar os resultados em cada questão. Tirei um print pra mostrar. Os valores são apresentados todos juntos e não separadamente para que cada questão valide eles. Podem me ajudar?

```
function eMaior (numeros){
  return Math.max (10,9)+ ", " +(5,11)+ ", " +(4,4)+ ", " +(2,120);
 }
```

Obrigada :)[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia coloca o código na pergunta? -1

Comment: código colocado!!

Answer (score 1):

Olá.

Na própria questão está dizendo que tem dois parâmetros na função `eMaior`.

Então faça isso:

```js
function eMaior (numA,numB){
  return Math.max(numA,numB);
}
var test = (eMaior(10,9) == 10);
// eMaior retorna 10
var test2 = (eMaior(5,11) == 11);
// eMaior retorna 11
console.log(test);
// retorna true
console.log(test2);
// retorna true
```

Comment: nesata no caso - 

function dobroDoProximo(numero){
  var resultado = [6, 1, -3];
  return resultado *2
}

não reconhece por que?

Ps. Obrigada :)

Comment: Porque o `resultado` é um array e não um número.

Comment: No caso pra retornar um valor válido e separado para cada questão deveria ser assim

```
function dobroDoProximo(numero){
  var somaA = 6+6;
  var somaB = 1+1;
  var somaC = -3+-3;
  var resultado = [somaA, somaB, somaC];
  return resultado
}
```

Comment: Sim. Isso mesmo

Answer (score 1):

Uma abordagem ainda mais direta para esse problema seria criar uma referencia para o método `Math.max`, já que a função `eMaior` irá retornar o mesmo resultado.

```
var eMaior = Math.max
```

Funcionando:

```js
var eMaior = Math.max;

console.log('Maior número entre 10 e 9: ' + eMaior(10, 9));
console.log('Maior número entre 5 e 11: ' + eMaior(5, 11));
```